# How can i mount /dev/shm in a docker container

Tags: docker, lxc

I created a Docker container, but now I need `/dev/shm` as a `tmpfs` mounted inside of the container.

If I manually change the `config.lxc` file in the Docker folder and uncomment the mount `/dev/shm` line, Docker seems to hang.

Moreover, the file gets recreated from time to time.

I need to know where I can change the Docker configfile that creates the lxc configuration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has been fixed with docker v0.6.0. Can you try again with the last version? (the lxc config is already set to mount /dev/shm)

Comment: Yes the compiled in template changed in 0.6